# I am trying to install MinGW but it's always failing to install

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I am trying to install MinGW but it's always failing to install.
on windows 7

link of the program:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download

Comment: Include the error message or screenshot please

Comment: mingw-get: *** ERROR *** http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-bin.tar.xz?download:cannot open URL
mingw-get: *** ERROR *** Get package: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/mingw-get-0.6.2-mingw32-beta-20131004-1-bin.tar.xz?download: download failed

Comment: Why are you using mingw? It's outdated. Use mingw-w64 instead

Comment: i always get a zip file not exe file

Comment: Extract it and then run the mingw-get in the bin folder

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: Extract the zip using 7z or any other software, go to the folder where you extracted it, then go to bin, then run mingw-get.exe

Answer (score 0):

Tar zips are not generally for windows users the downlink should be a windows installer mingw-get-setup.EXE thus (not a GnuZip)

Also if your trying to unpack 32bit collections the question is which architecture do you need, certainly 32.exe will run on 64, but 64.exe will NOT work on 32.

Current build is 32bit "Although (currently) offering only a 32-bit compiler suite, all of MinGW's software will execute on the 64bit Windows platforms."

get it from official https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/releases/
latest link I got was
https://osdn.net/frs/redir.php?m=liquid&f=mingw%2F68260%2Fmingw-get-0.6.3-mingw32-pre-20170905-1-bin.zip

once you have a valid windows .zip file, right click to "extract" then the exe should be in the bin folder.

Then it's just you on your own, and the myriad of instructions from google.

Answer (score 0):

MinGW is a compiler generating files for the Windows platform, but MinGW itself can also be run on other platforms (like Linux for example).

What you need is are Windows binaries of MinGW.

But MinGW is a bit outdated and only supports 32-bit Windows.

I would really recommend using MinGW-w64.

Standalone build of MinGW-w64 for Windows (both 32-bit and 64-bit) are available at https://winlibs.com/ just download the archive and extract it. Then all the tools you need will be in the mingw32/bin or mingw64/bin folder.

If you're not very familiar with command line tools you should really use an IDE. There are some instructions on https://winlibs.com/ on how to use MinGW-w64 with [Code::Blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/).

If on the other hand you are very familiar with command line or the Linux shell you should take a look at [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) which also allows installing MinGW-w64 with it's `pacman` tool.